# Basis for a subspace of $\Bbb R^5$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be the subspace of $\Bbb R^5$ defined by:

$$U=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in\Bbb R^5:x_1=3x_2 \text{ and }x_3=7x_4$$

I want to find the basis of this, and my attempt is below.

Comment: I think the protocol for verification is to add your attempt to the question itself.

Comment: @copper.hat can you please look at the discussion in the answer comments? I will make a post on meta when my rep activates it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible basis for your subspace is the following set
$${(3,1,0,0,0),(0,0,7,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1)}$$
It's clear that these vectors are linearly independent. We just need to show that they span the subspace. Consider any vector $V$ in your subspace. Let
$$V=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$$
But your condition restricts $V$ to 
$$V=(3x_2,x_2,7x_4,x_4,x_5)$$
But $V$ can be written as
$$V=x_2(3,1,0,0,0)+x_4(0,0,7,1,0)+x_5(0,0,0,0,1)$$
This shows that every vector in your subspace is a linear combination of the vectors from the constructed set. And the set is linearly independent. Hence the set has to be a basis.

Comment: Thank you Bolt, that is a beautiful answer. What is the correct notation for writing the basis down? $\operatorname{Basis } U = \{...\}$?

Comment: I'm not aware of any 'correct' notation for writing the basis down. As far as I know, every place I've seen, the author just decides to call a set a basis, say $B$, but there's no special notation.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous posters actually showed linear independence, so here it is: [Actual Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7OOG.jpg)

$$U = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$$$$=(3x_2,1x_2,7x_4,1x_4,1x_5)\}$$
$$=\{x_2(3,1,0,0,0)+x_4(0,0,7,1,0)+x_5(0,0,0,0,1)\}$$$$=Span\{(3,1,0,0,0),(0,0,7,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1)\}.$$ Row reduce the matrix A = [$v_1 v_2 v_3$] as shown in the linked image. Since $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is linearly independent and spans U, it is a basis for U. If we're using Axler's book, and need to extend the list to a basis for $\mathbb{R^5}$, then append $(1,0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0).$ Furthermore, $$W = Span\{(1,0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0)\}$$ is a subspace whose direct sum with U is $\mathbb{R^5}.$

Answer (score 0):

The basis for $U$ here is $$\{(3,1,0,0,0),(0,0,7,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1)\}$$

This spans the subspace, and it's vectors are linearly independent.

The correct notation here is:

$$\operatorname{Basis }U=\{(3,1,0,0,0),(0,0,7,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1)\}$$

Comment: You don't need to post the question and explain what you did in an answer. You should delete this answer and copy what is written here in the question.

Comment: Some justification is likely needed. The three vectors are clearly linearly independent, but how do you know they span $U$?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 But then if I am correct, the answer would be "Yes" which would be silly, and I won't know if I am upvoted for my question or my answer

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thank you, does that include my attempt at the notation? Or should it be a list like in the book? $\operatorname{Basis } U = ((3,1,0,0,0),(0,0,7,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1))$ instead of a set?

Comment: That's what comments are for. There's also a tag called proof-verification which is exactly for what you're doing. The fact that you're asking means there are some parts you're having trouble with, an answer would have to aim to clarify this parts. So unless you already know the answer, there'd be something to add, as @PVAL just did.

Comment: @PVAL Good point I will add that in

Comment: @hjhjhj57 It says that it is acceptable to post your own answers in the help page, and also are you saying I am getting free rep for posting my own answers? I have done this 5 times and I have 21 rep...

Comment: Forget what I said about the reputation, I just think is is not the way of asking (and think that users that have been around for a while shouldn't encourage it). And in fact, you're not even sure your answer is an answer, that's what the question is for.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 I want to be able to discern if my question or my answer are the upvoted thing and if I get upvoted I know it is the right answer, and if it is downvoted I will delete

Comment: Well, I disagree with your way of doing things, but we have a democratic community here, so let's see what happens (more like what meta and the moderators have to say).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20262/discussion-between-makoto-and-hjhjhj57).